# Recovered a 7z password with hashcat, but it's not the right one

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking, hashcat, 7zip

I am trying to recover a 7z file, but have forgotten the password. It's completely AES-256 encrypted (i.e. not even the filenames are available).

Steps:

1. Generated hash file with `7z2hashcat.pl`
2. Ran a mask attack using `hashcat -a 3 -m 11600 my.hash masks\rockyou-7-2592000.hcmask`
3. After ~55 hours, hashcat completed with status `cracked`
4. The password identified in the `hashcat.potfile` is rejected by 7-zip

I found a discussion on hash collisions with old Office files here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/211924

Is 7zip similarly vulnerable to hash collisions?

I would just try the steps in the linked post and see if I could generate more passwords, but given it could tie up my GPU for weeks, I'd appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: And, the version of 7-Zip?

Comment: Unknown, the file was created in 2016, so not a recent version

Comment: Is the password in the potifile maybe saved in Hex Format and not as a normal string?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, it suffers with hash collision

You should (in this case) use:
`--keep-guessing`

Since with 7z passwords may have false positives, you need to keep guessing to see other alternatives. To save progress on hashcat you should use

```
--session SESSION_NAME [and any other commands like -w -a]
```

Then to restore from last checkpoint:

```
--session SESSION_NAME --restore
```